# Excel adding rows to a table and automatically adding rows to another

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have two excel tables on two separate sheets. Both tables have a ID column and a many more columns that have nothing similar between the two tables (IE the tables store different things entirely). I want to sync them up so that whenever I add rows to one of the tables, it automatically adds a row to the other table.

So far, all I can get is having the ID in one of the tables directly reference the ID in the other table, but upon adding a row, it 1) doesn't automatically add another row (I didn't expect it to work though), and more importantly, 2) the cell references break. By that, I mean that they no longer hold a 1:1 relationship, and upon adding a new row, there will be a row that isn't referenced at all, and a row that is reference twice.

I've tried paste-special with different links, but nothing else functions any better. Any thoughts? I'm not particularly keen on a VB solution, I'll only use it as my last resort. I'd much prefer some help making something native in Excel that 'just works'.

Comment: Sorry. There is nothing native in Excel that will "just work". If you wish to add to *either* table and have the other one auto-magically insert a row, the magic is called VBA ;-) And a big g'day mate to a fellow aussie.

Comment: Hope the Australian winter is treating you well haha. Ahh, well I don't need it to be able to work on either table, only one of them will have items added to it, and I'd need those additions reflected in the other table. I would seriously like to avoid using VB for this particular project (both because I dislike it and because I think it's too overkill for this project) but if I have to, I may as well. Any particular advice for making this work properly?

Comment: Depending on precisely what you are doing with the two tables, this *can* be done just with formulas, but possibly with severe restrictions - namely neither of the two tables can ***ever*** be sorted, and rows can ***never*** be deleted if data is manually added to both tables. You need to be a bit more specific as to how you are populating the table data and what sort of editing is allowed. As for the weather, my definition of too cold is: anything below 15 degrees as a minimum. Got below 5 a couple of nights ago. Brrr!

Comment: One of the tables is entirely vlookups and sumifs and so on pulling data out of the master register (using that data in the column I am trying to edit). The second sheet should have the same first column for every single row, but it is all manual data entry. I'm not really sure how else to explain it. The weather down here has been enough that I am needing to de-ice the windscreen every morning. This is almost absurd

Comment: Sounds do-able. You just need to pre-fill the first table with a simple formula to pull in the ID either with a lookup or directly with a relative cell reference. If you want to allow sorting, then the formula has to be a lookup based on the current row.